# IO schedulers and VM host

Tags: linux, virtualization

What is the optimal IO scheduler to use for VMWare host machine?
(using VMWare Workstation on Linux, Ubuntu 9.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benchmark it and see, but I find deadline generally works best for server-type workloads.